# add duck-typed struct to dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, duck-typing

I want to add a duck-typed struct to an dictionary but i get the following error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from '[] options>' to 'UnityEngine.Object'

This is the code i have:

```
public class Dynamic_Interface
{
    private static Dictionary<int, Object> Interface_steps = new Dictionary<int, Object>();

    Dynamic_Interface()
    {
        var sentences = new[] 
        {
            new
            {
                identifier = 1,
                text = "string explain",
                options = new[] 
                {
                    new
                    {
                        next = 2,
                        value = "this is the first option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 2,
                        value = "this is the second option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 2,
                        value = "this is the third option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 2,
                        value = "this is the fourth option"
                    },
                }
            },
            new
            {
                identifier = 2,
                text = "string explain second var",
                options = new[] 
                {
                    new
                    {
                        next = 3,
                        value = "this is the second first option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 3,
                        value = "this is the second second option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 3,
                        value = "this is the second third option"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        next = 3,
                        value = "this is the second fourth option"
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        foreach (var sentence_obj in sentences)
        {
            Interface_steps.Add(sentence_obj.identifier, sentence_obj);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the end i want a dictionary containing each object in the `sentences[]` that has the the `identifier key` as name in the dictionary.

I am used to to javascript and this is really my first time doing c# so sorry for the beginner mistake. But i really cant seem to find how to get this to work.
If something is unclear let me know so i can clarify..

Comment: it would be easier to create a class which can hold the sentences, since duck-typing is rather prone to errors

Comment: You are using `UnityEngine.Object` instead of `System.Object`, probably because you only have the `Unity` stuff imported. To fix it use `System.Object` in the dictionary declaration or import the correct Namespace

Comment: @Freggar thanks this works! if you write it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what is happening here?
When we take a closer look at the error message

> Argument 2: cannot convert from '[] options>' to 'UnityEngine.Object'

it tells us that we are trying to convert the options array to the type `UnityEngine.Object`. Hmmm. this is weird we didn't define our Dictionary with this Unity nonsense, so why is it using that instead of C#'s Object class?!

Well you are propably using other Unity classes an probably have something like

```
using UnityEngine;
```

in your namespace. The problem with C# is that it's `Object` class also resides in a namespace which is called `System`, making it only fully identifieable by using `System.Object`. So if you don't have

```
using System;
```

it will happily try to use `UnityEngine.Object` instead of `System.Object` when you type `Object`. Thus this weird compiler error will occur.

---

So just use `System.Object` and everything is fine *right*?
*Well Yes. But there is more to the Story!*

C# also has defined aliases for it's most common types - the so called [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table) types:

```
bool        System.Boolean
byte        System.Byte
sbyte       System.SByte
char        System.Char
decimal     System.Decimal
double      System.Double
float       System.Single
int         System.Int32
uint        System.UInt32
long        System.Int64
ulong       System.UInt64
object      System.Object
short       System.Int16
ushort      System.UInt16
string      System.String
```

You will find that lowercase `object` is just an alias to `System.Object`. But wait! Doesn't that make `object` *always* use `System.Object` regardless of our using statements?  The answer is yes, yes it does...

Let me illustrate by following example how tricky namespacing in C# can actually be:

```
public class Object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TestConsole
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object fakeObject = new Object(); // -> Custom Object class
        object realDeal = new object();   // -> System.Object

        string name = fakeObject.Name    // OK
        name = realDeal.Name             // NOT OK
    }
}
```

So does that mean that we should always use the built-in alias when using System classes? Not really but we should *rather* use the naming convention that is used by Microsoft. That means whenever you use the class like a datatype you should use the built-in and whenever you use static members of the class you should use it's full name. For example:

```
object humberto = "humberto";
string rudolf = "rudolf";
Object.Equals(humberto, rudolf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strong typing is one of advantages of C#, its a bit more verbose than ducktyping but saves you a lot of headache, if possible try to restrain from var, its a few characters shorter but if you use strong types its much harder to accidentally ask the compiler to do something different than what you actually want:

Two options for alternative approaches that seem to immediately stand out are

```
class myClass { int next; string value; };
Dictionary <int, myClass> dict;
```

or, possibly, although I think this is not quite what you are trying to do

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,string>> dict;
```

Second option doesn't require you to declare a class type, but remember that dictionaries require unique keys. It kind of reads that you want to use array index as a key, but then you still use a dictionary, is there a reason for that? My solutions might be a bit off, but I'd be happy to suggest more if you could explain what kind of lookup you want to make.

Maybe you want to combine the above into

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,myClass>> dict;
```